# How to convert and send string in Http Authorization Header?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a REST API. Client puts it's user name and password in authorization header of `HttpClient` after encrypting it with public key of Server. Username and password will always consist of alphabets and number which means it can be represented in ASCII.

I am using this code for encryption.

```
string encrypted = Encrypt (someText, crypto);

    public static string Encrypt (string plainText, RSACryptoServiceProvider crypto)
    {
        var plainData = GetBytes (plainText);
        var encryptedData = crypto.Encrypt (plainData, true);
        return GetString (encryptedData);
    }

    public static byte[] GetBytes (string str)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof (char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy (str.ToCharArray (), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    public static string GetString (byte[] bytes)
    {
        var chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof (char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy (bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string (chars);
    }
```

Problem is that I get this string after encryption

> ꠨屰欧㼡‫⭮鍴⬎㔾䐛え멩戻덒郝㬭ே䉚ꑰ䵇᷹᷶虣ⱒ̿ঊࠎ飳枹鬭쉦폩��ᤫ槺愐丄裘ډ졽肟䷋ٱ᮷튼쁡鮤붮飦ꃨ◡뉋⭠夏旻浨፛᠏რ

I can't send these Unicode characters in the authorization header. Is there any way to get the encrypted text in ASCII so that it can easily be sent through HttpClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode it. Base64 encoding produces a string that is suitable for sending over a transport that supports ASCII strings.

```
public static string Encrypt (string plainText, RSACryptoServiceProvider crypto)
{
    var plainData = GetBytes (plainText);
    var encryptedData = crypto.Encrypt (plainData, true);
    return Convert.ToBase64String (encryptedData);
}
```

Btw, I would replace your custom GetBytes method for converting the string to an array of bytes with `Encoding.GetBytes`; which is the built in and preferred method of doing that. For instance:

```
var plainData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just do a minor change `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes`